# Firefox not showing console.log on mouseover

Tags: javascript, firefox

I use Firefox 56.0.1 without Firebug. Code is simple, but in FF I get nothing in console. In Chrome all works. I started FF without any extensions in safe mode and nothing has changed.

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
    
      $("#card").mouseover(function() {
        console.log('mouseover!');
       });
    })
```

```css
#card {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:#CCC;
margin:50px;
}

body {
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="card"></div>
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: Working fine on FF 56/Win 10 here

Comment: Does it work fine here on stackoverflow?

Comment: That's why I'm asking. I can not figure out for myself why it does not work.

Comment: Sort of impossible to help you out. All I can say is clear your cache to make sure you have the latest and greatest code.

Comment: @epascarello Yes it works in a snippet. But snippet has own console.log as I understand.Thanks for help!

Comment: It shows the `console.log` in the snippet **and** my FF56 console on stackoverflow.

Comment: @ProgFeets and it also logs to the regular console too. Make sure you do not have any filters enabled on the logs in your FF Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. It was necessary to change the theme from Firebug to any other. Because while the Firebug theme is active, options will be marked as active even if they are disabled:
[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iXrGAc8PjKo)